# Apache2 - Can't access subfolders of /var/www/html from Network Computer - Ubuntu Server 16

Tags: networking, server, permissions, apache2

I likely have a simple problem that I am just unsure how to handle. We had to switch machines one of our internal sites is on and after much work, we've got everything set, except for some reason, we can access the base folder through using the machines ip address, but not any folders underneath (where the internal site is).

So if I go to 192.168.1.130, I get the: Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page (It Works!) page.

However, if I add /providence to the url, which is a folder, I have double checked, as well as made sure that the contents were there, I get: The connection has timed out

"The server at 192.168.1.130 is taking too long to respond" and it gives up after about 8-9 seconds. But if I return to the previous page, it loads in under a second.

Is this a permission issue? And what might I do to rectify it?

Thanks! Matt

//UPDATE

Here is my "providence" folder, which is what contains the internal application.

[image]

Here is my root html folder, which is where I can view the Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page but nothing else.

[image]

Comment: What are your permissions and ownership of the files?

Comment: @PasiSuominen - See my update, I'll also quickly grab the same for the html root folder just in case.

Comment: @Matthew: Please post also your virtual host's configuration file.

Comment: Can you see your http error log file, i think problem lies in your apache conf: <Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>